Xcode Asset validation failed Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle
Has anyone had this error with Xcode 15?
I've already added the images and added a line to my configuration file.
I have already followed various suggestions, but none of them work.

Take a look @ this thread - https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-assets/issues/231

This describes your problems also in detail - https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/92638

When you look at the Asset Bundle, is the icon a separate asset of type "App Icon", not "Image"? [Tap on asset then look at upper-right of display]
